# drop down menu will not work

Tags: javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that is supposed to work with four different menu choices, each given the same class. But my code is not working. I want it to work with both chrome and IE. The situation where it crashes is in my init method. The console complains as following: Object # has no method 'getElementsByTagName'.  Any solution ?

```
function hideorShowField(list) {
    var nodes = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].style.display == 'none') {
            nodes[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            nodes[i].style.display = 'none';
       }
    }
}

function init() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("undermeny");
    list1.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onclick = function () {
        hideorShowField(list);
    };
}

window.onload = init;
```

My html code:

```
<ul class="undermeny" >
<li>Opinion</li>
<li><a href="#">Ledare</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Aktuella frågor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Per T Ohlsson</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Magda Forsberg</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="undermeny" >
<li>Lokalt/Globalt</li>
<li><a href="#">Malmö</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lund</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Limhamn</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Burlöv</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Eslöv</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Höör</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kävlinge</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lomma</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Svedala</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staffanstorp</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Trelleborg</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vellinge</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sverige</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Öresund</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Världen</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Väder</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="undermeny" >
<li>Ekonomi</li>
<li><a href="#">Nyheter</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privata pengar</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Börs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fonder</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="undermeny">
<li>Sport</li>
<li><a href="#">Fotboll</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ishockey</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Handboll</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fridrott</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i noticed that list1.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onclick = function () { hideorShowField(list); }; is supposed to be list and not list1. but it still wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a `nodeList` as well as `getElementsByTagName()`. So you probably need this:

```
list[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onclick = function () {...};
```

Or you've to iterate over the `list`to attach eventhandlers to all 1st `li`elements within `ul`s with class `undermeny`. That'll be something like this:

```
for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    list[n].getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onclick = function () {...};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list1` has not been initialized (although `list` has). Fix the typo, and then you can iterate over the items in `list`, calling `getElementsByTagName()` on each.